# Can you capture the event when clicking on the month name in jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the [jquery ui datepicker inline mode view](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline)

I want to be able to capture when a user clicks on the month name at the top (as i then want to zoom into a more detailed month view.

is this possible to capture this click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element has a `ui-datepicker-month` class, so you can just do this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-month").live("click", function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xHGdb/), keep in mind this is *only* the month, change the selector to  this if you want to include clicks on the year as well: `".ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year"`.

Comment: how can you get which month you clicked (as i am showing multiple months)

Comment: @ooo - You can use `$(this).text()` to get the label, or are you after something else?

Comment: for month and year, you can also use ".ui-datepicker-title"

Comment: Any updates on this? I tried `$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-month', callbackFct)`, and this doesn't seem to work. Using jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: I had the same problem. Calling the code with a delay solved my problem.  `setTimeout(function() {$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-month', callbackFct)}, 1);`